# Call downstream assets or ops in parallel with Dagster

Tags: python, dagster

I build a data pipeline with Dagster using the `asset` API.

I am looking for a way to explicitly call/execute an `asset` (or `op`) for a list of items. While `assets` are executed in parallel if they are independent, I did not find a way to include iteration.

Simple example: Iterate over a list of files and perform a task for each file. The tasks are independent.

```py
@asset
def iterate_files():
    path = Path("/some/path")
    
    for file in path.iterdir():
        # here I would like to start parallel ops
        ...
```

If I pass a list to a downstream `asset`, the operation is performed sequentially:

```py
@asset
def list_of_files():
    path = Path("/some/path")
    return list(path.iterdir())

@asset
def process_files(list_of_files):
    for file in list_of_files):
        with open(file, 'rt') as f:
            for line in f:
                # write to a DB or other operation
```

Is it possible to achieve a parallel execution of the downstream task with Dagster?